# Dynamic selection of 2nd item from a static dropdown using cypress

Tags: javascript, cypress, ui-automation

to automate CRUD functionality I need to select the 2nd item from a static drop down and the html is like

```html
<select name="segment[segment_contact_id]" id="segment_segment_contact_id">
   <option value="73082">Rita Basu</option>
   <option value="73349">researcher user</option>
</select>
```

So by using cypress I am using the hardcoded value and my code is like

```js
const segmentUser2 = 'researcher user'
const userValue2 = 73349
cy.get('select#segment_segment_contact_id')
  .select(segmentUser2)
  .should('have.value', userValue2)
```

I need suggestion because I don't like to use the hardcoded value instead I would like to use always the 2nd item from the drop down dynamically.

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like this

```
Cypress.Commands.add(
  'selectNth',
  { prevSubject: 'element' },
  (subject, pos) => {
    cy.wrap(subject)
      .children('option')
      .eq(pos)
      .then(e => {
        cy.wrap(subject).select(e.val())
      })
  }
)
```

Usage

```
cy.get('[name=assignedTo]').selectNth(2)
```

Comment: Can I get an example in function form , just don't want to create a custom command for it.

Comment: This is a much cleaner test. With a function you loose chaining.

Answer (score 2):

Here is @ItsNotAndy's way without the custom command.

```js
cy.get('select#segment_segment_contact_id')
  .children('option').eq(1)
  .then($option => {
    cy.wrap($option).parent().select($option.val())
  })
```

**As a function**

```js
function selectNth(selector, pos) {
  cy.get(selector)
    .children('option').eq(pos)
    .then($option => {
      cy.wrap($option).parent().select($option.val())
    })
}

selectNth('select#segment_segment_contact_id', 1)
```

**Verifying from text displayed**

```js
cy.get('select#segment_segment_contact_id')
  .find(':selected')
  .contains('researcher user')
```

**Verifying by selectedIndex**

```js
cy.get('select#segment_segment_contact_id')
  .its('0.selectedIndex')
  .should('eq', 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this as well. Here first we are getting value of the second item in the list using the `eq()` command. Then once we have got the value, we are just simply passing that to `select()`.

```js
cy.get('select#segment_segment_contact_id option').eq(1).invoke('val')
  .then((val) => {
    cy.get('select#segment_segment_contact_id').select(val)
  })
```

And if you want to just validate the value or text you can do:

```js
cy.get('select#segment_segment_contact_id option')
  .eq(1).should('have.value', 73349)
cy.get('select#segment_segment_contact_id option')
  .eq(1).should('have.text', 'researcher user')
```